# Insufficient storage Rally

Tags: rally

Here is my very basic code:

```
def get_role_permission

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "userpermission"
query.fetch="Role"
query.page_size=20
query.limit=20

result = @rally.find(query)

#result = build_query("UserPermisson","Role,User","","(Role= \"Viewer\")")

if(result.length!=0)
  puts "Got some result"

else
  puts "No result"
end

end
```

This function returns :

```
`send_request': RallyAPI - An issue occurred (HTTP-507) on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/userpermission.js. (StandardError)
Response was: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 507 Insufficient Storage</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 507</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /slm/webservice/1.37/userpermission.js. Reason:
<pre>    Insufficient Storage</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>      <br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

Has anybody encountered such an error before? I am assuming that my query is correct and I am not querying any restricted attribute.

Comment: This error would come up when a query requires more resources than what our servers can provide and maintain a healthy response for our users. Do you get this consistently with the exact same code? I tested your code without making any changes, other than adding `puts result.first.Role`, and it returned: "Got some result User". There was no HTTP-507.

Comment: @nickm I get the output 3 out of 10 times. Other times I get this error, would you suggest any change in my code to avoid this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

You may narrow a query, e.g. filter out some roles

```
query.query_string = "(Role != \"Viewer\")"
```

Here is a code I tested a dozen of times to see if I get 507:

```
@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :userpermission
query.fetch = "Role"
#query.limit = 1000
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111.js" } #optional

query.query_string = "(Role != \"Viewer\")"
result = @rally.find(query)
count = 0
if(result.length!=0)
    puts "Got some result"
    result.each do |r|
        puts "#{r.Role}..." 
            count += 1
    end
    puts count
else
  puts "No result"
end
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I added workspace and project to the query just to narrow down the results. Also added a couple of constraints to the query string .Still couldn't get the result. Do I need to contact Rally developer support for this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Do you get the same 507 error or a different error? Would you please update your question with the exact code with which you can replicate the problem? If you contact support please make sure to attach your code.

Comment: Here is a link to my current code: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6252361/

Yes, I still get the same 507 error

Comment: So it's basically both userpermission as well as projectpermission that give me the 507 error.

Comment: Rohan, I added a count variable to my code just to see how many results I get. I ran your code against a larger set of my data and the count printed out 48339 while `query.query_string = "(Role != \"Viewer\")"` was commented out - I did not even narrow the query. I am afraid I do not know why your code does not work for you. Please try adding this line to your code `query.limit = 10` to see if that allows you to avoid 507, and gradually increase this number.

Comment: I have requested support from Rally and shared my code. For the last time, can you please check the code [here](https://github.com/rohandalvi/CLI/blob/master/helper.rb) and see if it works for you. I am still getting the same 507 error even after adding `query.limit=10`. Thanks.

Comment: Rohan, 507 indicates that a  query requires more resources than a server can provide, but it does not necessarily mean Rally server. It is appears that the error is generated before the request reaches Rally. I did not find a single 507 returned by Rally servers within a week, so I would suggest that you test your code outside of your local network if possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39509/discussion-between-rohan-dalvi-and-nickm)